# AC-circuit with resistors and capacitors in series and parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Circuit]
Is there any frequency for E, where the potential between A and B is zero in this circuit?

I tried using the jw-method to get the current, but it became to complex which tells me that there must be a shorter way.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say you tried the "jw" method.  Any solution to this problem will use Z = 1/(jwc) as a starting point.  You will rarely get far asking about homework questions here unless you point out specifically where you got stuck.

Comment: Also, the answer is.... w = 0!

Comment: @Selvek no, the answer is f=160 Hz

Comment: sin(0) = 0 so at w=0 all the voltages are 0.

Comment: @Selvek You can’t have a frequency that’s zero. If that was the case you would have a wavelength that’s unlimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help!

[image: Voltage dividers]
Voltage dividers:

(1) $$\frac{1}{Z_1}=\frac{1}{Z_C}+\frac{1}{R} 
\Leftrightarrow Z_1=\frac{R\cdot Z_C}{R+Z_C} $$

$$ \frac{V_A}{E}
=\frac{R}{Z_1+R}=
\frac{R}{\frac{R\cdot Z_C}{R+Z_C}+R}
=\frac{R}{\frac{R\cdot Z_C + R(R+Z_C)}{R+Z_C}}
=\frac{R(R+Z_C)}{R(R+2Z_C)}
=\frac{R+Z_C}{R+2Z_C}$$

(1) $$ \frac{V_B}{E}
=\frac{2R}{(R+Z_C)+2R}
=\frac{2R}{3R+Z_C}
$$

$$ V_{AB}=0 \Leftrightarrow V_A=V_B$$

$$\frac{R+Z_C}{R+2Z_C}=\frac{2R}{3R+Z_C}$$

$$(R+Z_C)(3R+Z_C)=2R(R+2Z_C)$$

$$3R^2+4RZ_C+Z_C^2=2R^2+4RZ_C$$

$$R^2=-Z_C^2$$

\$Z_C=\frac{1}{j\omega C} \Rightarrow \$

$$R^2=-\left(\frac{1}{j\omega C}\right)^2
=\frac{-(-1)}{(\omega C)^2}
=\frac{1}{(\omega C)^2}$$

$$R=\frac{1}{\omega C}$$

$$\omega=\frac{1}{RC}$$

\$\omega C=2\pi f \Rightarrow \$

$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi RC}
=\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot 10^3 \cdot 10^{-6}} \; Hz
=\frac{500}{\pi}\; Hz
\approx 160  \; Hz$$

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to calculate any currents.  The circuit is set up as 2 voltage dividers. Calculate the voltage at A using the usual formulas for the impedance of a capacitor and a voltage divider.  Then calculate the voltage at B using the same formulas. Equate the two voltages (since if they are equal, there is no potential between A and B) and solve for the frequency. The answer is very simple in terms of R and C. Then substitute the given values of R and C to find the actual frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully. The voltages \$U_a\$ and \$U_b\$ are the same if

$$2 \cdot (X_C||R) = X_C + R$$

$$2 \cdot \frac{X_C \cdot R}{X_C + R} = X_C + R$$

$$2 X_C R = (X_C + R)^2 $$

$$2 X_C R = X_C^2 + 2 X_C R + R^2 $$

$$0 = X_C^2 + R^2 $$

$$- X_C^2 = R^2 $$

With \$X_C = -\frac{1}{j\omega C}\$

$$-(-\frac{1}{j\omega C})\cdot(-\frac{1}{j\omega C}) = R^2$$

$$-((-\frac{1}{j})^2)\cdot(\frac{1}{\omega C})^2 = R^2$$

$$-(j^2)\cdot(\frac{1}{\omega C})^2 = R^2$$

$$1 \cdot(\frac{1}{\omega C})^2 = R^2$$

$$\frac{1}{\omega C} = R$$

It's often easiest to keep \$X_C\$ and \$X_L\$ in the formulas as long as possible.

Comment: When I look carefully, I see $$½ \cdot (X_C||R) = X_C + R$$

Comment: Oh, you are right. But I miscalculated before, it's simply too late in the night for me.

Comment: Yeah, but please correct my actual calculation the way Tony suggested. The result isn't as simple as above then (it was just too tempting to assume it would be simple.)

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn4ei4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We know that $$Z_{C}(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi fC} = \frac{1}{2\pi f \cdot 0.000001}$$

Then, the only remaining thing to do is to find the possible solutions of :
$$\frac{R}{(Z_C(f) \parallel R) + R} = \frac{2R}{R + Z_C(f)}$$

When both of the "branches" will look alike at some frequency \$f_{answer}\$, then A and B will be held at the same ratio of \$V_1(t)\$ and hence will have the same electrical potential.

There is no need to compute currents, as for an fixed frequency AC **voltage source**, the capacitors only "look" like an impedance **when you're interested in voltage**. If you were interested in current, then you would need to compute the phases.

If the source was a current source instead, it would be reversed. The currents would be "easy" to compute but you would need to account for the phases in order to calculate voltages.